# nopCommerce Index Page -> How does it render all the sections?

Tags: view, nopcommerce

I am looking at the nopCommerce source code. Somehow the front office page shows Categories, Manufacturers, Poll, Featured Product, Search etc... however I am just looking at the source code of the Index.cshtml and I can't see any code to do this. The source code of the Index is attached. The link to the demo page is http://demo.nopcommerce.com/

I was expecting the Index page to render partial views or will have the code to create these sections but nothing there.

Can anyone explain how nopCommerce renders the views?

Is there any docs to explain technical side of nopCommerce. I have read the user guide but it does not have any details.

```
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_ColumnsThree.cshtml";
}
    <div class="page home-page">
        <div class="page-body">
           @Html.Widget("home_page_top")
            @Html.Action("TopicBlock", "Topic", new { systemName = "HomePageText" })
            @Html.Action("HomepageCategories", "Catalog")
            @Html.Action("HomepageProducts", "Catalog")
            @Html.Action("HomepageBestSellers", "Catalog")
            @Html.Action("HomePageNews", "News")
            @Html.Action("HomePagePolls", "Poll")
            @Html.Widget("home_page_bottom")
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: I think the quickest way to answee your question is that those sections are defines in Shared\_ThreeColumns.cshtml this is basically the Layout (master page) of Index. If you want to modify this, I recommend you to recreate the same file inside your theme folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is nothing unique to nopCommerce, **Html.Partial** & **Html.Action** are normally used in all ASP.NET-MVC applications. Partial and Action act similarly to render reusable partial views. Only difference is that **Partial** works with current model, while **Action** retrieves additional data.

**HomepageCategories**, **HomePagePolls** etc views are located under **Views > Catalog > HomepageCategories.cshtml** inside NopCommerce application folder and if you'd like to change them, you can copy the View folder into your theme folder and edit it there so you don't have to modify original files.

Comment: Thanks I have always used HTML.RenderPartial or HTML.Partial but never used Html.Action. Do you know the advantages of using .Action instead of .Partial or .RenderPartial?